# How to get Micrometer to output all custom metrics

Tags: java, datadog, micrometer, statsd

I am using Micrometer 1.9.0 and Spring boot 4.2.16 to report metrics to DataDog over StatsD. Some metrics are showing up, but very few. Using the Metrics Explorer in DataDog, it's very hard to find any metrics at all because they are so scarce.

To test this locally, I started up https://hub.docker.com/r/jonmorehouse/dogstatsd-local/dockerfile/ and it does display all of the standard metrics provided by Micrometer, and very occasionally displays one of my custom metrics.

I have set breakpoints and verified that my `Counter` instances are being incremented on every request to my application, but for some reason very few metrics are written to StatsD.

All of my metric reporting is encapsulated in a class called `Metrics` which is autowired into controllers etc. The `Metrics` class looks like this:

```java
package com.****.metrics;

import com.****.commons.metrics.MetricId;
import com.****.commons.metrics.MetricTagName;
import com.****.commons.metrics.MetricTagValue;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.DistributionSummary;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Metrics {

  private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;
  private final DistributionSummary orderCountDistribution;

  public Metrics(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;

    DistributionSummary.Builder builder =
        DistributionSummary.builder(MetricId.UPDATED_ORDERS_COUNT_DISTRIBUTION.getValue())
            .description("Records the average number of modified orders returned")
            .tags(MetricTagName.PURPOSE.getValue(), MetricTagValue.ANALYTICS.getValue())
            .tags(MetricTagName.LAYER.getValue(), MetricTagValue.DATA.getValue())
            .minimumExpectedValue(1d)
            .maximumExpectedValue(100d)
            .publishPercentileHistogram();
    orderCountDistribution = builder.register(meterRegistry);
  };

  public void recordApiRequest(
      String apiVersion,
      String controller,
      String endpoint,
      String method,
      long elapsed,
      TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    Counter.Builder counterBuilder =
        Counter.builder(MetricId.API_REQUEST_COUNT.getValue())
            .description("Counts the number of API requests")
            .tags(MetricTagName.PURPOSE.getValue(), MetricTagValue.ANALYTICS.getValue())
            .tags(MetricTagName.LAYER.getValue(), MetricTagValue.ENDPOINT.getValue())
            .tags(MetricTagName.API_VERSION.getValue(), apiVersion)
            .tags(MetricTagName.CONTROLLER.getValue(), controller)
            .tags(MetricTagName.ENDPOINT.getValue(), endpoint)
            .tags(MetricTagName.METHOD.getValue(), method);
    Counter counter = counterBuilder.register(meterRegistry);
    counter.increment();

    Timer.Builder timerBuilder =
        Timer.builder(MetricId.EXECUTION_TIME.getValue())
            .description("Records the time taken to process an API request")
            .tags(MetricTagName.PURPOSE.getValue(), MetricTagValue.PERFORMANCE.getValue())
            .tags(MetricTagName.LAYER.getValue(), MetricTagValue.ENDPOINT.getValue())
            .tags(MetricTagName.API_VERSION.getValue(), apiVersion)
            .tags(MetricTagName.CONTROLLER.getValue(), controller)
            .tags(MetricTagName.ENDPOINT.getValue(), endpoint)
            .tags(MetricTagName.METHOD.getValue(), method);
    Timer timer = timerBuilder.register(meterRegistry);
    timer.record(elapsed, timeUnit);
  }

  public void recordExecutionTime(
      String module, String operation, long elapsed, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    Timer.Builder builder =
        Timer.builder(MetricId.EXECUTION_TIME.getValue())
            .description("Records the time taken to complete an operation")
            .tags(MetricTagName.PURPOSE.getValue(), MetricTagValue.PERFORMANCE.getValue())
            .tags(MetricTagName.LAYER.getValue(), MetricTagValue.PROCESSING.getValue())
            .tags(MetricTagName.MODULE.getValue(), module)
            .tags(MetricTagName.OPERATION.getValue(), operation);
    Timer timer = builder.register(meterRegistry);
    timer.record(elapsed, timeUnit);
  }

  public void recordUpdatedOrderCount(int orderCount) {
    orderCountDistribution.record(orderCount);
  }
}
```

What could be causing the sparse output of data?

Answer (score 1):

> I am using Micrometer 1.9.0 and Spring boot 4.2.16

I'm pretty sure you don't, the highest version of Boot is 3.0.2 at this very moment and it was 2.7.x when you wrote this.

> What could be causing the sparse output of data?

I guess sparse traffic. But please try two things:

1. If you use a Java agent, please try to remove it and check again
2. Check `/actuator/metrics` endpoint: if you see the data there, it might be something over the network that drops the data (e.g.: UDP is not very good for this)