# How do I get custom metrics done in micrometer to graphite?

Tags: spring, micrometer

Similar to [How to get Micrometer to output all custom metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73589046/how-to-get-micrometer-to-output-all-custom-metrics) but I am trying to do it for Graphite.

I have a custom metric counter defined as:

```
  @Bean
  Counter successfulAuthenticationRequests(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {

    return Counter.builder(metricPrefix + ".auth.authentication.success")
        .tag("group", "authentication")
        .tag("state", "ok")
        .register(meterRegistry);
  }
```

In actuator I can see the value

```
❯ curl http://localhost:28082/actuator/metrics/spring.cloud.gateway.auth.authentication.success | jq
{
  "name": "spring.cloud.gateway.auth.authentication.success",
  "measurements": [
    {
      "statistic": "COUNT",
      "value": 2
    }
  ],
  "availableTags": [
    {
      "tag": "node",
      "values": [
        "docker-desktop"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "service",
      "values": [
        "ds_gateway"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "state",
      "values": [
        "ok"
      ]
    },
    {
      "tag": "group",
      "values": [
        "authentication"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The environment is set up as

```yaml
  management.graphite.metrics.export.host: graphite
  management.graphite.metrics.export.enabled: "true"
  management.graphite.metrics.export.port: 2004
```

And I can see that there's data added to Graphite so I presume the connection is all valid.

However, I can't see my custom counter.  I tried to use a different prefix as well and none of it worked.

Is there anything I may be missing?

[image]

I also tried to [disable tag support](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/graphite#_graphite_tag_support) by adding

```
management.graphite.metrics.export.graphiteTagsEnabled: "false"
```

I get more metrics with this set in Spring but not for my custom metrics.

Answer (score 0):

So if your problem is the same: seeing sparse data can be caused by

1. Sparse traffic
2. Something on the network drops the data

> And I can see that there's data added to Graphite so I presume the connection is all valid.

That only means that you were able to connect and send at least one data point. It does not mean that all of your data points reached the destination.

Also, if you use a Java agent, please try to remove it and check again.